# popViewController(animated: true) animation works slow

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a tap gesture recognizer added on the imageView, so when user taps on the image below function is called.

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

When I am pushing to detail view controller animation looks fine and works smooth, but when I am using the above method to popViewController(animated: true) animation is not so smooth and might even freeze for a second.

I am also using viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods to hide navigation bar in detail view controller. I have read that this could cause animation to work slow, but still could not manage to find answer how to solve this.

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }
```

Comment: Assigning `navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden` doesn't effect performance that much. My app is working smoothly with so many of these assignments. Some works that effect your UI would be starting or ending camera sessions, initialising GMSMapView, etc. Could you kindly update the post with full code of your View Controller class so that other can reproduce your bug and find a better solution suitable for your situation.

Comment: It's very strange, because when I am using custom-made animation for popViewController, therefore setting default animation to false everything work smooth with the custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not sure but it may work

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: Have tried it, does not work for me. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your override of `viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` you call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`.  As you have probably figured out by now, you should be calling `super.viewDidDisappear(animated)` instead.  Your corrected code should read:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```